# Chartjs datalabels is not showing the labels on the bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a vertical bar chart built via chartjs. I'm using the datalabels plugin, I expect the data to be plotted on each bar but it's not visible

```js
const data = [
    {
        "date": "2023-02-23",
        "subscribers": 1208123
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-22",
        "subscribers": 1045338
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-21",
        "subscribers": 1043130
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-20",
        "subscribers": 1248035
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-19",
        "subscribers": 1243734
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-18",
        "subscribers": 1240317
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-17",
        "subscribers": 1033439
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-02-16",
        "subscribers": 974864
    }
];
  const chart_label = "Number of subscribers";

 const chart_canvas = document
      .getElementById("number_of_messages_delivered")
      .getContext("2d");
    Chart.defaults.set("plugins.datalabels", {
      color: "#FE777B",
    });
    push_messages_chart = new Chart(chart_canvas, {
      type: "bar",
      options: {
        animation: true,
        plugins: {
          // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
          datalabels: {
            color: "#FFCE56",
            display: true, // Set to true to display the labels
          },
        },
      },
      data: {
        labels: data.map((row) => row.date),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: chart_label,
            data: data.map((row) => row.subscribers),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="number_of_messages_delivered"></canvas>
```

I tried different iterations since last week, but nothing worked. This is just a random sample of what I've tried

Comment: What data are you missing? Seems to work fine?

Comment: @0stone0 I'm using datalabels plugin in order to draw the number on the bar itself, the plugin isn't working, the number isn't visible on the bar unless you hover. But the hovering behavior isn't related to the plugin, it's a built in functionality. I want to draw the number of subscriber on the bar, so you can see the number without hovering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the plugin!

Add this:

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

---

Some additional info / improvements

- The `color` of the `datalabels` should be inside the `labels.value` object. I've moved that so the lables are the correct color (`#FFCE56`)
- The `color` on the `dataset` should be `backgroundColor`, changed that as well
- I've implemented a `formatter` on the label with the use of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-format-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators) on how to apply thousand-seperators, just to make it more readable (again).

  ```
  formatter: n => numberWithCommas(n),
  ```

---

###### Updated Snippet

```js
const data = [{"date": "2023-02-23", "subscribers": 1208123 }, {"date": "2023-02-22", "subscribers": 1045338 }, {"date": "2023-02-21", "subscribers": 1043130 }, {"date": "2023-02-20", "subscribers": 1248035 }, {"date": "2023-02-19", "subscribers": 1243734 }, {"date": "2023-02-18", "subscribers": 1240317 }, {"date": "2023-02-17", "subscribers": 1033439 }, {"date": "2023-02-16", "subscribers": 974864 } ]; 
const chart_label = "Number of subscribers";
  
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels); // Enable plugin

const chart_canvas = document
      .getElementById("number_of_messages_delivered")
      .getContext("2d");

push_messages_chart = new Chart(chart_canvas, {
    type: "bar",
    options: {
        animation: true,
        plugins: {
            // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
            datalabels: {
                formatter: n => numberWithCommas(n),
                display: true, // Set to true to display the labels
                labels: {
                    value: {
                        color: "#FFCE56"
                    }
                } 
            }
        },
    },
    data: {
        labels: data.map((row) => row.date),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: chart_label,
                data: data.map((row) => row.subscribers),
                backgroundColor: "#FE777B",
            },
        ],
    },
});

function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="number_of_messages_delivered"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, will accept your answer in 4 minutes, I just thought that this initializes the plugin `Chart.defaults.set("plugins.datalabels", {`